# spring scheduler starts running even before server starts

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I have created a spring scheduler in Spring boot application, but the scheduled job starts even before the server started. Is it possible to start the scheduler after server start?

One way is to have a flag and check for that flag on every run, but this is just a workaround. I can paste scheduler code too but that is quite straightforward, so I am not adding it in the first place,

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void onServerStart() {
    this.serverStart = true;
}

@Scheduled(initialDelayString = "${betsync.adapter.check.connection.fixedDelay.in.milliseconds}",
            fixedDelayString = "${betsync.adapter.check.connection.fixedDelay.in.milliseconds}")
    public void restartSessionForInactiveSession() {
}
```

I am using an initial delay but it's not guaranteed to start after server start

Comment: What is the schedule set to? Are you using with annotation?

Comment: yes, I have added my scheduler signature

Comment: I notice you have set `initialDelayString` to `betsync.adapter.check.connection.fixedDelay.in.milliseconds`. Notice the value used is `[..]fixedDelay[..]` and not `[..]initialDelay[..]`. Could you be using the wrong value?

Comment: I agree with @Idva that you are using wrong values. You are referring to fixDelay in both  initialDelay and fixDelay. Try to correct that first.

Comment: initialDelay ask the scheduler to wait for the asked time after the component is created otherwise, it will fire the scheduler straightaway after creating the component. I have used the same delay at both the place, but even if I use different it doesn't matter.